# Power BI "distinct count" DAX function for handling a text variable that satisfies two conditions?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to generate a distinct count of a text variable that satisfies two conditions; "critical" and "not-critical", where I am only interested in "critical".

Can someone suggest an appropriate DAX function to try? I have a very layered data-set.

I've tried a number of different DAX functions including IF, GROUPBY and SUMMARIZE but to no avail.

If "team a" is assessed as "critical" and "non-critical";
"team b" is assessed as "critical";
"team c" is assessed as "non-critical".

I have a "critical" count of 2 and a "non-critical" count of 2.

However I only want to include the "critical" assessment of "team a" and ignore/exclude the "non-critical" assessment.

The expected results would be a "critical" count of 2 and a "non-critical count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt to your actual table structure, but something like:

```
Critical Count = 
CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( MyTable[Team] ),
    MyTable[Status] = "Critical"
)
```

and

```
Non-Critical Count = 
SUMX ( 
    VALUES ( MyTable[Team] ),
    ( [Critical Count] = 0 ) * 1
)
```